# How to insert an element <item>..</item> inside the channel element in a RSS feed using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss

I'm looking to create an rss feed for a website using C#. What I'm trying to approach is, once I clicked a button ("Add Feed"), it suppose to create and a Node Element, like this:

```
<item>
 <title> some title...here </title>
 <link> link to the article ...here </link>
 <description> article's description ...here </description>
</item>
```

This has to be a child of the <channel> element. So, so far with the code I wrote, it inserts the elements described above in the rss xml file, but it does it outside the <channel> element, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Example Home Page</title>
    <link>http://www.example.com</link>
    <description>Educational Website...</description>
    <image>
      <url>http://www.example.com/images/logo.png</url>
      <title>Example.com</title>
      <link>http://www.example.com</link>
    </image>
    <category>Photography</category>
    <language>en-us</language>
  </channel>
<item>
 <title> some title...here </title>
 <link> link to the article ...here </link>
 <description> article's description ...here </description>
</item>
</rss>
```

This is the code :

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

  XmlNode item = doc.CreateElement("item");

  XmlNode Title = doc.CreateElement("title");
  Title.InnerText = TextBoxTitle.Text;
  item.AppendChild(Title);

  XmlNode link = doc.CreateElement("link");
  link.InnerText = "http://www.example.com/" + DropDownListCategory.SelectedItem.Text + ".aspx?key=" + TextBoxLink.Text + ".txt";
  item.AppendChild(link);

  XmlNode description = doc.CreateElement("description");
  description.InnerText = TextBoxDescription.Text;
  item.AppendChild(description);

  doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(item);
  doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/rss.xml"));
```

How can I do that ?  Any help or feedback will be appreciated.  Thank you !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if i understood the requirements correctly:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  XmlNode rss = doc.CreateElement("rss");
  XmlAttribute version = doc.CreateAttribute("version");
  version.Value = "2.0";
  rss.Attributes.Append(version);
  XmlNode channel = doc.CreateElement("channel");

  XmlNode item = doc.CreateElement("item");

  XmlNode Title = doc.CreateElement("title");
  Title.InnerText = "Title Text";
  item.AppendChild(Title);

  XmlNode link = doc.CreateElement("link");
  link.InnerText = "http://www.example.com/.txt";
  item.AppendChild(link);

  XmlNode description = doc.CreateElement("description");
  description.InnerText = "DESC";
  item.AppendChild(description);

  channel.AppendChild(item);
  rss.AppendChild(channel);
  doc.AppendChild(rss);
  doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/rss.xml"));
```

Ok now that we got that the file is already saved somewhere, try this:

```
  var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/rss.xml"));

  XmlNode channelNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::channel");

  if (channelNode != null)
  {
    XmlNode item = xmldoc.CreateElement("item");

    XmlNode Title = xmldoc.CreateElement("title");
  Title.InnerText = "Title Text";
  item.AppendChild(Title);

  XmlNode link = xmldoc.CreateElement("link");
  link.InnerText = "http://www.example.com/.txt";
  item.AppendChild(link);

  XmlNode description = xmldoc.CreateElement("description");
  description.InnerText = "DESC";
  item.AppendChild(description);

  channelNode.AppendChild(item);
  }
  doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/rss.xml"));
```

Comment: Cool habit of appending the big stuff in the end.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I tested your code, while it does what I want, which is adding the <item> element inside the <channel> node. The problem with this approach, is that every time you click the button to add new content, the old content will be deleted. I like to have everything intact, just add new <item>....</item> elements. Like the way I do with my approach. What I don't do right, is to add these elements <item> inside the <channel> node. I have to say that I have created the rss.xml structure manually, the only thing I want to do programmatic, is to add the <item> nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The .net framework has built in support for building RSS feeds in `System.ServiceModel` (you need a reference to System.ServiceModel.dll), it might be better to use it to guarantee valid RSS xml, and it's nicer to work with anyway that constructing the XML yourself. Futher reading [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For example..

```
// read in the existing rss xml
var rssFeedXml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\rss3.xml"); // replace with server.mappath etc
var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(rssFeedXml.CreateReader());      
var items = new List<SyndicationItem>(feed.Items);
feed.Items = items;

// add the new item
items.Add(
        new SyndicationItem(
        "some title...here ",
        "some description here",
        new Uri("http://example.come")));

// write the xml back out
var rssFormatter = new Rss20FeedFormatter(feed, false);
XDocument output = new XDocument();
using (var xmlWriter = output.CreateWriter())
    rssFormatter.WriteTo(xmlWriter);

output.Save(@"c:\temp\rss.xml");
```